# Is this question a good candidate to downvote?

Tags: discussion

Is this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/725/seeking-a-recommendation-for-a-preferably-free-project-management-app) a candidate for downvote?

I would think yes for following reasons

1. I think is more a discussion question than a technical one with a specific problem
2. This gives a chance for people to promote their products. We would not want our site to be downgraded for promotional activities. ( i am not picking on anyone who answered the above question but suggesting that this could be misused.)
3. No research effort done
4. Off Topic?

Would love to know what the community thinks of it. As much as i hate to downvote we might need use it to keep the site clean.

Answer (score 2):

I think that I agree with 3 of your 4 points. And like other SE sites, we also are not planning to be a buying guide.

But, #2 will open a HUGE door regarding the AppExchange - do we offer solutions there or not?
regardless of the free/paid version - once we open that door, than why not offer a solution that is not within the AppExchange market?

I can see myself downvoting this question, or even flag it - as the major point of the question is actually for a discussion.

Comment: #2 is a bit murky, there could be times when the solution to something is an App in the AppExchange (e.g., some solid app for exporting data).  This particular question seems off topic to me.

Comment: Yea, but until we don't have an FAQ of what is and what isn't, it's a votedown only I guess. (that's if we are trying to be Politically Correct)