# Are questions about Apps in the App-exchange off-topic?

Tags: discussion

As we start to get more questions, and either they will be like:

- Has anyone tried _______________ fromr StackExchange?
- Can anyone suggest of a free/paid app that does __________ ?

How are we going to address that?

Some questions already in this area are:

- [Seeking a recommendation for a (preferably free) Project Management app?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/725/seeking-a-recommendation-for-a-preferably-free-project-management-app)
- [How to create a lead from an email?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/75/how-to-create-a-lead-from-an-email)
- Also note this comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/722/260 - User is endorsing the company he works at
- do we flag off topic?
- votedown?
- delete?

If we do allow, which as @PeterKnolle mentioned on [Is this question a good candidate to downvote?](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/is-this-question-a-good-candidate-to-downvote) - it's murky

- do we allow to advertise (yes, that's the word) free? paid apps?

I guess we need to address this, and sooner the better.

Answer (score 8):

I'm personally against soliciting direct opinions on AppExchange products for multiple reasons, primarily because I don't think SFSE should be a product review site. I would suggest either flagging them as off topic or using comments to steer them to a better question. That being said, if a "How do I" question can be answered *well* through a product on the AppExchange I see nothing wrong with that. A good example might be "What's a good way to manage permissions?" and somebody points App X.

When it comes to employees mentioning their company's product I'm OK with it as long as they mention the affiliation, which Toan did.

Comment: I agree with @Mike Chale about not soliciting direct opinions.  We definitely do not allow free advertising.  If it feels anything like that it should be flagged as spam immediately.  Our faq: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion.  I have faith in our voting system.  I think it is definitely good that this is being brought up now, so that everyone is aware of it.

Comment: I think that some of these questions also tend to be good candidates for Community Wiki.  If it's a broad enough "how do I" question, there may not be a single good answer.

Answer (score 3):

Questions about how to use a specific app in the app exchange are probably alright although there might not be many people who could answer it if it's not a widespread app. There are a lot of app developers here though so some of those questions could definitely get answered.

Questions whose answer may be an app recommendation also seem to be fine to me, although we want to make sure the questions aren't being asked solely to setup another user to come in and post an ad. I guess that's kind of hard to monitor though.

I agree that soliciting recommendations are outside of scope, e.g. "Is app X worthwhile?"

Comment: I agree with most of what you said, except the first part. I would rather see questions on how to use App X be relegated to that company's own boards.

Comment: I thought about that - but this whole site is about another company's application where we didn't find that company's own boards to be good enough. For some this may be the best place to get those questions answered.

Comment: I think "How do I do X with Y app" could be a good fit here.  I'd just recommend a tag like "3rd-party-app"